# How to scale down a div that contains text?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, scale

I am trying to shrink a circle by 50% upon mouse click. I did it by using jQuery UI's scale effect.

The div is

```
<div id='circle' class='circle'></div>
```

The Js is

```
var percent = 0.5;

$('#circle').click(function () {
    var height = $(this).height();
    var width = $(this).width();
    var centerX = $(this).position().left + $(this).width()/2.0;
    var centerY = $(this).position().top + $(this).height()/2.0;
    $(this).effect( "scale", { percent: percent * 100 }, 1000, function () {
        var newTop = centerY - (height * percent)/2.0;
        var newLeft = centerX - (width * percent)/2.0;
        $('#circle').offset({ 'top': newTop, 'left': newLeft });
        $('#circle').css({'height': height * percent, 'width': width * percent });
    });
});
```

That piece of code worked until i added some text on the circle like

```
<div id='circle' class='circle'>
  <span class="title">Title</span>
</div>
```

The title did scale down with the circle but upon completion it restored to the original size and made the circle a oval. Please try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marsant/Ycakg/

Is there a neat way to solve this problem other than manually tweaking the completion callback? Thanks!

Comment: `display: table-cell` simulates the behaviour of a real table's cell (all cells have equal height, content cannot escape its container/the cell, and cells do not have margins but they can have padding and borders). Also, any float applied to display: table-cell elements cancels the effects of table-cell. Because of this, once you reach the width of the text, the div can't get any narrower, thus turning it into an oval. You'll either need to go to another display setting, or scale the text down with the width/height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a quick fix by adding something like:

```
$(this).find('*').filter(function(i) { return $(this).text != "" && !$(this).children().length }).each(function(i) {
    var curSize = parseFloat($(this).css('fontSize'));
    $(this).css('fontSize', curSize / 2);
});
```

- `$(this).find('*')`: get all inner elements of the circle div
- `.filter(function(i) { return $(this).text != "" && !$(this).children().length })`: narrows our result to only inner elements that have text and no other inner elements
- `.each(function(i) {`: begins going through each element so we can change it's font size
- `var curSize = parseFloat($(this).css('fontSize'));`: get the current font size of the current inner element
- `$(this).css('fontSize', curSize / 2);`: Set this inner elements font to a new font size that is half the old

If you want to jazz it up a little to kind of match your reanimation you could go with:

```
var curSize = parseFloat($(this).css('fontSize')),
        newSize = curSize / 2
    $(this).animate({ fontSize: newSize });
```

Although if you want it to match exactly to the animation, you'll probably need to find a CSS solution or change your whole script a bit. I'll look, one sec ...

<kbd>**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kmcAg/)**</kbd>

---

USING ANIMATE TO DO IT ALL AT ONCE:

```
$('#circle').click(function () {
    var height = $(this).height(),
        newHeight = height / 2,
        width = $(this).width(),
        newWidth = width / 2,
        fontSize = parseFloat($(this).css('fontSize')),
        newFontSize = fontSize / 2,
        newLeft = parseFloat($(this).css('left')) + (newWidth / 2),
        newTop = parseFloat($(this).css('top')) + (newHeight / 2);

    $(this).animate({ 
        height: newHeight,
        fontSize: newFontSize,
        left: newLeft,
        top: newTop,
        width: newWidth 
    });
});
```

**NOTE** This requires slight change in CSS. I would change the `.circle` to have position `relative` and move the `font-size: 80px;` to the `.circle`:

```
.circle {
    background:red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 80px;    
    position: relative;
}
.title {
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'Helvetica';
}
```

<kbd>**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CYmfq/)**</kbd>

Comment: He could switch to using .animate so that he can animate width/height/fontsize all at once. Too bad animation promise objects don't trigger the progress event on each step, that would have made this simple.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the 'font-size' for the title. I changed it from **80px** to **5em**. Then it seems working smoothly. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marsant/kmcAg/1/

Comment: But then how to get the **em** value from a float value for font-size?